# Model selection and interpretation with many factors (not all are significant)

Tags: mixed-model, categorical-data, feature-selection, interpretation, model-selection

How I worked:

Initial model

```
lme.full <- lme(antotal_denLOG ~ fland20soil + fland20grass + fland20herb + fland20agri + fland20shrubs +
                     fland20trees + fland20rock +fland1soil + fland1grass + fland1herb 
                   + fland1shrubs + fland1trees + fland1rock, data=habitat, random = ~ 1 | site, method = 
              "ML")
```

- Response variable is a density
- Variables of the fixed part are all factors with ±7 levels each
- Site is chosen as a RE since it had quite some variance of residuals between sites

For selection of the optimal model I used the `drop1` function with a $\chi^2$ test. Removed every variable which wasn't significant according to the $\chi^2$ test and resulted in a lower AIC value.

However, at some point in the model selection I ended up with a model that had two factors which were according to the $\chi^2$ test not significant but results in a model with a higher AIC value:

```
    drop1(lme.drop9, test="Chi") 
Single term deletions

Model:
antotal_denLOG ~ fland20shrubs + fland20trees + fland1herb + 
    fland1trees
              Df    AIC    LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
<none>           387.77                     
fland20shrubs  6 395.35 19.574 0.0032961 ** 
fland20trees   5 403.08 25.306 0.0001216 ***
fland1herb     5 388.11 10.336 0.0662573 .  
fland1trees    6 387.29 11.514 0.0737447 .
```

At the end I kept them in the model due to their subject-matter (ecological) relevance and since they resulted in a better fit on the Q-Q plot than without `fland1herb` and `fland1trees`.

**Q1:** Is this a right justification to keep these variables in the model?

In order to check the main effects of each  variable I used ANOVA:

```
> anova(lme.fit)
              numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)       1    78 137.67199  <.0001
fland20shrubs     6    78   1.46930  0.1997
fland20trees      5    78   2.94578  0.0173
fland1herb        5    78   1.22387  0.3059
fland1trees       6    78   1.36103  0.2409
```

**Q2:** As you can see, only `fland20trees` is significant whereas the other are not. But I'm not quite sure what ANOVA does here? Does it compares the effect of each variable to the intercept?

**Q3:** See output below. As you can see due to the many levels per factor the output is quite large and some levels are significant predictors whereas other are not even close to being significant ($p$-value<0.05). So how do I interpret this output with these differences in significance between the levels within the same variable? Can I still use a variable even if it contains different significance between levels?

```
> summary(lme.fit)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: habitat 
      AIC      BIC    logLik
  412.577 485.5765 -181.2885

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | site
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.2659565 0.7164701

Fixed effects: antotal_denLOG ~ fland20shrubs + fland20trees + fland1herb +      fland1trees 
                    Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)     1.0482853 0.3204626 80  3.271163  0.0016
fland20shrubs2 -0.0136391 0.3888310 80 -0.035077  0.9721
fland20shrubs3 -0.6928349 0.4032024 80 -1.718330  0.0896
fland20shrubs4 -0.1197633 0.3702077 80 -0.323503  0.7472
fland20shrubs5 -0.7732211 0.4222515 80 -1.831186  0.0708
fland20shrubs6 -0.9121404 0.4211904 80 -2.165625  0.0333
fland20shrubs7 -0.7215368 0.5263134 80 -1.370926  0.1742
fland20trees2   0.1165120 0.2652419 80  0.439267  0.6617
fland20trees3   0.3805516 0.2740516 80  1.388613  0.1688
fland20trees4   0.9337469 0.2859544 80  3.265369  0.0016
fland20trees5   1.1598144 0.3043016 80  3.811398  0.0003
fland20trees6   1.2261600 0.6568181 57  1.866818  0.0671
fland1herb2    -0.2602729 0.1795524 80 -1.449565  0.1511
fland1herb3    -0.5402645 0.2116408 80 -2.552743  0.0126
fland1herb4    -0.3272119 0.2352794 80 -1.390738  0.1682
fland1herb5    -0.0767546 0.3094198 80 -0.248060  0.8047
fland1herb6    -0.6711334 0.7855727 80 -0.854324  0.3955
fland1trees2    0.1674138 0.3255888 80  0.514188  0.6085
fland1trees3   -0.0018254 0.3137017 80 -0.005819  0.9954
fland1trees4   -0.4461270 0.4557413 80 -0.978904  0.3306
fland1trees5   -0.5018836 0.3546865 80 -1.415006  0.1609
fland1trees6   -0.4969408 0.4391451 80 -1.131610  0.2612
fland1trees7   -1.1284479 0.4449397 57 -2.536181  0.0140
 Correlation: 
               (Intr) flnd20s2 flnd20s3 flnd20s4 flnd20s5 flnd20s6 fln207 flnd20t2 flnd20t3 flnd20t4 flnd20t5
fland20shrubs2 -0.758                                                                                        
fland20shrubs3 -0.760  0.720                                                                                 
fland20shrubs4 -0.829  0.765    0.824                                                                        
fland20shrubs5 -0.717  0.705    0.817    0.810                                                               
fland20shrubs6 -0.724  0.718    0.809    0.812    0.842                                                      
fland20shrubs7 -0.596  0.573    0.657    0.657    0.684    0.702                                             
fland20trees2   0.016 -0.277   -0.261   -0.312   -0.307   -0.358   -0.257                                    
fland20trees3   0.059 -0.176   -0.424   -0.345   -0.485   -0.437   -0.367  0.476                             
fland20trees4   0.056 -0.211   -0.400   -0.306   -0.522   -0.452   -0.432  0.453    0.706                    
fland20trees5   0.053 -0.194   -0.374   -0.289   -0.452   -0.494   -0.494  0.455    0.662    0.723           
fland20trees6   0.047 -0.079   -0.171   -0.154   -0.240   -0.113   -0.335  0.180    0.323    0.391    0.418  
fland1herb2    -0.277  0.008    0.100    0.124    0.037    0.074    0.123 -0.038   -0.156   -0.152   -0.140  
fland1herb3    -0.200 -0.003    0.089    0.069    0.138    0.101    0.097 -0.076   -0.255   -0.234   -0.230  
fland1herb4    -0.139 -0.045    0.060    0.068    0.082    0.060    0.119 -0.110   -0.323   -0.194   -0.236  
fland1herb5    -0.108 -0.004    0.020    0.053    0.027   -0.024    0.069 -0.023   -0.243   -0.179   -0.117  
fland1herb6    -0.037  0.001   -0.046    0.033    0.024    0.012    0.032 -0.028   -0.131   -0.071   -0.055  
fland1trees2   -0.015  0.024    0.008   -0.006   -0.039   -0.036    0.045  0.031   -0.039   -0.075   -0.111  
fland1trees3    0.024  0.015   -0.018   -0.016   -0.039   -0.025    0.025  0.014   -0.015   -0.100   -0.040  
fland1trees4    0.023  0.004   -0.001   -0.012   -0.007   -0.135    0.035  0.053    0.025   -0.057   -0.099  
fland1trees5    0.024  0.002    0.004   -0.015    0.004   -0.158    0.058  0.055    0.002   -0.073   -0.186  
fland1trees6   -0.031 -0.004    0.017    0.014    0.017   -0.119    0.000  0.031   -0.041   -0.071   -0.176  
fland1trees7   -0.082  0.004    0.048    0.025    0.047   -0.091    0.154  0.018   -0.103   -0.201   -0.202  
               flnd20t6 flnd1h2 flnd1h3 flnd1h4 flnd1h5 flnd1h6 flnd1t2 flnd1t3 flnd1t4 flnd1t5 flnd1t6
fland20shrubs2                                                                                         
fland20shrubs3                                                                                         
fland20shrubs4                                                                                         
fland20shrubs5                                                                                         
fland20shrubs6                                                                                         
fland20shrubs7                                                                                         
fland20trees2                                                                                          
fland20trees3                                                                                          
fland20trees4                                                                                          
fland20trees5                                                                                          
fland20trees6                                                                                          
fland1herb2    -0.119                                                                                  
fland1herb3    -0.221    0.483                                                                         
fland1herb4    -0.171    0.428   0.438                                                                 
fland1herb5    -0.143    0.344   0.316   0.326                                                         
fland1herb6    -0.050    0.117   0.111   0.126   0.198                                                 
fland1trees2   -0.078    0.049   0.037  -0.183   0.070   0.030                                         
fland1trees3   -0.027   -0.061  -0.117  -0.081  -0.191   0.083   0.104                                 
fland1trees4   -0.122   -0.057  -0.116  -0.055   0.042   0.003   0.113   0.082                         
fland1trees5   -0.192   -0.083  -0.049  -0.009   0.071   0.010   0.142   0.087   0.351                 
fland1trees6   -0.387    0.098   0.091   0.123   0.127   0.034   0.103   0.042   0.189   0.287         
fland1trees7   -0.563    0.252   0.258   0.218   0.216   0.063   0.119   0.050   0.166   0.236   0.335 

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.6108318 -0.6110960 -0.1227865  0.6307770  2.6695450 

Number of Observations: 160
Number of Groups: 60
```

**Q4:** I know the intercept functions as a baseline so in this case the intercept should be `fland20shrubs1`, right? But what about the other variables and their first level?